# "createRenderThread failed to connect" when starting an Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the following issue, or what tools may be available for me to try to resolve this. I get this error when I try to start a Jelly Bean VM.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_7'
createRenderThread failed to connect
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I've tried executing it from the command line as:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator -avd Nexus_7 -memory 1024
```

And still no-go.  I can't see any way to get more detailed information.  And I really don't know where the **8** comes from from memory allocation.

Here's my virtual device set-up:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Salsero69 I am facing the same issue.If you have found the solution.Please let me know.

Comment: There's been a few updates to the tools since, so not have been having those issues since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this was caused by blocking some of the traffic/ports in my firewall.

It appears that this message is shown also when the emulator can not be reached (e.g. by Eclipse). When this is the case, the following happens:

- the message (create render thread failed to connect) appears also while starting the emulator from AVD
- Eclipse does not 'see' running emulators and starts a new one for each run of the program
- Eclipse never manages to load apk into the emulator

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33930#c5) post can help you to solve this issue. Just download **tools_r19-windows.zip** zip file and replace the `tools` folder in your sdk with the one provided in the zip file. Later when you launch Eclipse, ignore the ADT version warning message and you are good to go.

I also had the same issue and this technique helped me to solve the problem.